# How to change a specific value in a dataframe

Tags: r

```
test2 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2), score = c(0, 100))
```

In above data frame, I want to change 1 as John and 2 as 3. How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As id is a sequence and we wanted to change values in the same order, use the 'id' as index for the `vector` of replacing values

```
test2$id <- c("John", 3)[test2$id]
```

Or as the sequence order is 1:n, just replace it with the `vector` of new values by assigning it to the 'id' column

```
test2$id <- c("John", 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the specific problem, then as @akrun has answered, you can just use `test2$id <- c("John", 3)`, since the vector is in sequence and the `$` operator references that row of the data frame.

If you want something more generalisable though, when looking for matches, you can point to only the matches and update only them.

```
test2$id[test2$id == 1] <- "John"

test2$id[test2$id == 2] <- 3
```

That updates all matches for `1` and all matches for `2`. If you just want to update items in sequence, go with the one line approach. If you want to update items based on their value, go with the matching approach.

If you will always want to match based on integers, @akrun's first solution is also a good one.